# Bookdown (gitbook) produces empty HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, gitbook

I am currently working on a book which I want to knit into a GitBook.

Yesterday the output looked amazing (thanks to bookdown).

Today, I modified just the simplest content of my book and tried to knit it again. All resulting HTML-files were empty, except for the `index.html`.

The same issue arises when I want to run the [minimal-book-example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo). Just to demonstrate, not even this small example is working:

**index.rmd**

```
--- 
title: "Very small example"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
description: "to demonstrate my problem"
---
# Well, I'm stuck.
```

**01-ChapterOne.rmd**

```
# Chapter One
Could anyone
```

**02-ChapterTwo.rmd**

```
# Chapter Two
please help me?
```

I do not receive any error messages, making it very hard to troubleshoot on my own. Also, the sidebar portrays the content of the book (all chaptes and subchapters) correctly. However, if you click on them, they are empty.

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

**R version:** 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

**RStudio version:** 1.3.1073

**bookdown version:** 0.20.6

The same (or a similar) issue was [raised here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookdown-blank-output-files-basically-the-output-in-html-is-blank-an-no-rmd-data-is-shown/8446) but unfortunately, no solutions were found.

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you use the kntir button in RStudio. This will just render the index.Rmd (when it is the current opened document).

From the console you have to use: `bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd', 'bookdown::gitbook')` or you use the `build` button in RStudio:

[image]

Comment: Dear sir/madam, thank you very much! Quite embarrassing to have overlooked that, but it's working. Thanks a lot again!